# How to fix " catch clause variable" Error?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I try to add firbase to my angular project. For that i use the command:

```
ng add @angular/fire
```

But it throws after choosing firestore the following error:

```
An unhandled exception occurred: catch clause variable is not an Error instance
```

Comment: Have you checked the log file after the stacktrace? A message like "See [PATH]/angular-errors.log" for further details". Can you share the content of this file?

Comment: [error] AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: catch clause variable is not an Error instance
    at assertIsError (/Users/eliahgerber/Documents/Modul 326 Projekt/asap-pay/asap-pay/node_modules/@angular/cli/src/utilities/error.js:19:26)
    at AddCommandModule.runSchematic (/Users/eliahgerber/Documents/Modul 326 Projekt/asap-pay/asap-pay/node_modules/@angular/cli/src/command-builder/schematics-command-module.js:304:43)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

Comment: at async AddCommandModule.executeSchematic (/Users/eliahgerber/Documents/Modul 326 Projekt/asap-pay/asap-pay/node_modules/@angular/cli/src/commands/add/cli.js:283:20)
    at async AddCommandModule.handler (/Users/eliahgerber/Documents/Modul 326 Projekt/asap-pay/asap-pay/node_modules/@angular/cli/src/command-builder/command-module.js:111:24)